# How can I define a formatter function for a Bootstrap slider in an Input tag?

Tags: reactjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-slider

I am using a Bootstrap slider on a web page in a React app. Because I can't use JQuery to define the slider, I have loaded the bootstrap-slider.min.js library and defined the slider with data- attributes to the input tag using this HTML code:

```
<input
    type="range"
    name="range-1a"
    id="range-1a"
    data-provide="slider"
    data-slider-min="0"
    data-slider-max="1000000"
    data-slider-step="500"
    data-slider-orientation="horizontal"
    data-slider-tooltip="show"
    data-slider-handle="round"
    data-slider-tooltip-split="true"
    data-slider-value="[0,1000000]"
    data-value="0,1000000"
/>
```

The slider displays correctly and tooltips appear over each handle as they are moved. But the tooltips do not have dollar signs and commas (so a value such as "100000" displays as "$100,000", for example).

The documentation for [Bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) states that a formatter object can be defined for the slider to format tooltip output, but it can't be set in a data-slider-formatter attribute.

How can I make this slider call a formatter() function to define the tooltip text?

Comment: You cannot do this, because functions can't be stringified like such. You must use javascript to pass a function.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to do something like this (which works outside of React) but I get a .slider() is not a function error in React:
    $(".range-slider-wrapper input").slider({
                formatter: function(value) { ...  }
        });

Comment: I'm not sure what to recommend you with React, as I don't personally use it, but I suspect React and jQuery do not play well together. You can use the library with vanilla JS however.